# After cancelling an edit, both "I'm Done" & "Not Sure" buttons are disabled

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, late-answers

This happen after the first review on review/late-answers.

After reviewing the first late answer, you're going to the next one. Both buttons are disabled when you arrive, which is normal but if you edit and then cancel the edit, both buttons are still disabled.

You can reproduce it:

- Go on https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers
- Review the answer
- Jump to the next one
- When the page is loaded **and before the <kbd>Not Sure</kbd> button becomes available**, edit the answer
- Now cancel the edit

You're stuck with no available action: both buttons are disabled.

Of course this doesn't happen when you don't cancel the edit.

**Edit:**

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

As @animuson said in comment, I also have the orange fade-away background sticked.

Comment: `and before Not Sure button become available` I tried, but it becomes available _almost_ instantly and couldn't reproduce this.

Comment: @YannisRizos I can make a screencast if you want, but I reproduce it on both Chrome 23 and Firefox 15.

Comment: The Not Sure button becomes available pretty much immediately for me. With ninja skills, I was able to get the orange fade-away background to stick when cancelling an edit: http://i.stack.imgur.com/mCM5j.jpg

Comment: @animuson I also have the orange fade-away background sticked

Comment: @j0k No need, I'm not disputing that this happens for you, I'm just saying that although there's a small delay until the Not Sure button becomes available, it's so small I couldn't reproduce this. Not fast enough I guess ;) Or it could be that your network is acting up and the delay is much larger for you, in which case that's not really a bug, at least not one that would affect most people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, good catch. We just deployed updated review javascript, so this should be fixed now.

Comment: Yep, problem fixed. *But* the orange fade-away background stay sticked. Which isn't a really bug I assume

Comment: That's a bug too. I'll take a look.

Comment: @j0k Ok, the background-color issue should be fixed now as well.