# Closing popup to reject an edit makes it impossible to approve it without reloading

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, suggested-edits, review

A bug manifests itself where if one originally decides to reject an edit, but then decides not to, they can potentially require a page reload. The button that changes to a gray `rejecting...` remains like that and is unclickable without a reload.

How to reproduce:

1. View a suggested edit in Review Beta.
2. Click the Reject button to get the reject popup.
3. Close the popup with `cancel` or the X in the upper left of the popup.

Observe lack of clickable button. I'll get a screenshot when there is a suggested edit on AU where I have the reputation to reproduce this bug.

This was tested [here](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/30416), on my own question, and this does appear when I try to review edits to my own question. This also occurs in the popover that appears if I click the `edit(1)` link below the post.

Comment: I just tested this from the Ask Ubuntu review page and I can confirm this bug occurs as described.

Comment: Just as a note, this was tested on http://askubuntu.com/review-beta/suggested-edits/30416

Comment: I also got it few times on SO.

Comment: I am also able to confirm this, with [that suggested edit](http://askubuntu.com/review-beta/suggested-edits/30416).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This javascript bug was introduced two days ago ([as part of this fix](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148220/144066)), but it's fixed now. Thanks for the report.