# I can't reconsider my decision to reject an edit

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Closing popup to reject an edit makes it impossible to approve it without reloading](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148338/closing-popup-to-reject-an-edit-makes-it-impossible-to-approve-it-without-reload)

When I am reviewing suggested edits, and I press the `Reject` button

[image]

and then I decide that I don't actually want to reject and I press the X to cancel,

[image]

all the review buttons have disappeared, replaced with a disabled `Rejecting...` button.

[image]

To get the buttons back, I have to refresh the page.

Shouldn't the buttons reappear when I close the rejection dialog window?