# Rejection Dialog in Review disappears if text is highlighted

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, suggested-edits, user-interface

While working my way through the review queue and after I rejected a question, I accidentally did not release my mouse button and proceeded to highlight some text.  When that happen the Reject dialog box disappeared and I was left in a broken state that I could not continue with the rejection and could only continue reviewing after refreshing the screen (or hit back on the browser).

I am currently using Chrome 25.0.1364.152 on Windows 7.

This seems like it could be related to this issue [Closing popup to reject an edit makes it impossible to approve it without reloading](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148338/182513), but that bug was reported as fixed back in September 2012

Here are the steps to reproduce (with pictures):

1. **Start with one standard suggested edit in review queue**
   [image]
2. **Reject the edit**
   [image]
3. **Click anywhere outside the dialog box**
   [image]
4. **Now left in unusable state (can be cured by refreshing and starting over)**
   [image]

Comment: I was expecting an "eeek" at any moment.

Comment: I knew I forgot something when I was capturing the screen shots.  Forgive me, it is my first bug report.  I'll do better next time :)

Comment: Also, we should do these every week. A sort of Where is Waldo style quiz.

Comment: your error report is good. i can confirm the behavior you describe

Comment: Reproduced on FF 17.0.3 ESR, Windows 7

Comment: @J.Steen http://i.imgur.com/3UwpBco.png

Comment: This is brand new behavior with brand new bug... you don't have to select anything enough to click anywhere outside the dialog. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd updated the repro steps.  Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.

Was a consequence of review having slightly different popup handling from the rest of the site, and handling its closures itself.  Recent changes that made all popups "click outside" to dismiss caused this case where actions wouldn't be re-enabled always.

I just brought review into line with the new dismissals.

Comment: I tried to reproduce again and the issue seems to be resolved, thanks.

Comment: This is happening [once again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208099/187824). But only if we click on `[X]` or `cancel` button or press `Esc` (i.e. it doesn't happen if we click outside the box).