# Closing Reject Suggested Edit dialogue freezes review process

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, suggested-edits

If you go to review a suggested edit and close the Reject dialogue box, the button at the top-right will continue to say "Rejecting...". You will not be able to continue with the review process.

I have refreshed the page, and tried clearing my cache. If I refresh the page, I can continue reviewing the edit.

I'm using Chrome Version 31.0.1650.57 m.

> [image]

Comment: I wonder if it's a Chrome 31 thing; I've heard at least a couple problems with it. Using Chrome 30 and have no problems with the queue.

Comment: Confirmed on the same version of Chrome, Win7 Pro x64. However, I am able to refresh the page and continue reviewing.

Comment: Worth to mention that it happens if you click the [X] itself or press ESC, clicking anywhere outside the dialog will close it properly and the buttons show just fine.

Comment: There is an error in the console when I see the issue.

Comment: @DennisMeng It's not just a Chrome 31 issue. I just reproduced it on my BlackBerry tablet.

Comment: Maybe it's a deliberate bug so that we don't click the reject button when facing positive audits?

Comment: Reproducible even on Firefox 25.0.1, Win7 Pro.

Comment: reproduced, fixing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix will be out in the next build; watch out for rev `2013.11.20.1664` on meta and `2013.11.20.1165` on sites