# Review buttons not displayed back

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits

I happened to notice a very strange scenario today when I was reviewing the suggested edits queue today. The review buttons were not displayed back after closing the reject window, rather it just used to stay as "Rejecting" and wouldn't go back to normal unless I refreshed the page. I was able to re-create this in almost every review. Here is a snapshot of what I'm talking about.

[image: Review Buttons not displayed back]

Steps to reproduce this:

1. Go to the suggested edits review page.
2. Click on the reject button.
3. Press the close button at the top or press the escape key.
4. And now you can see the buttons are not displayed back with a disabled Rejecting button.
5. Refresh the page and tada, its back to normal again.

Is this some sort of [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) or [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)? Btw, I'm using Firefox 25.0.1 on Windows 7, if that matters.

*P.S:* It seems that a similar(I guess the same) bug was reported long back [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170398/216721) and it was fixed by the dev team. But now, the bug seems to have cropped up again.

Comment: Wow. Ninja'd...

Comment: Maybe it's a deliberate bug so that we don't click that button while facing positive audits.

Comment: @R.J - If the duplicate question doesn't have any answer that doesn't mean you should ask another question to get an answer or we shouldn't close the question. Also the additional information can be added in the main question.

Comment: @hims056 - No love lost anwways :P Btw, can we post a comment to Kevin(in the question I linked in my previous comment) regarding this or let the decs find it out themselves?

Comment: @apaul34208 - Actually, I wasn't talking about the bug reported *9 hours* back. I never knew about it. I was talking about [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170398/216721).

Comment: @R.J - Yes why not.. I have commented on [his answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170398/rejection-dialog-in-review-disappears-if-text-is-highlighted#comment663556_170693).

Comment: oops sorry about that